# Performance of Open Source Time Series Database for Financial Market Data

Tags: time-series, database

We would like to store financial tick data in a database (potentially billions of rows) and then create aggregated (open-high-low-close) bar data from it (e.g. 1min or 5min bars).

It was mentioned to us that a NoSQL or time series database might be a good choice for this. Can anybody give any advice on which open source product might fit this requirement best.

Note: query performance is very important for us.

In our research we came across the following products (maybe there are more):

- [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/)
- [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/)
- [KairosDB](https://kairosdb.github.io/)
- [MonnetDB](https://www.monetdb.org/Home)

We did run a test with InfluxDB with around 10 million ticks. Unfortunately the creation of 1min bars was 3-5 slower than with a relation database (i.e. MySQL).

We are aware that KDB now offers a free 32-bit version, but unfortunately 32-bit will not be enough for our use case.

Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT (Sept 2015): We also did a test with OpenTSDB which seems to be quite fast. The import of 10 mio. prices took about one minute and the aggregation into 1 Min Bars took about 5 seconds.

EDIT (Jan 2017): More than one year after the initial test we gave InfluxDB another try and it turns out that they have made huge progress in the meantime. Write performance is now up to 2 mio. data points per second (with version 1.2)! We have now decided to integrate InfluxDB into our own product [AlgoTrader](http://www.algotrader.com/algotrader-3-1-integrates-influxdb/)

Comment: InfluxDB doesn't provides out-of-the-box Technical Analysis functions so how do you perform indicators calculation on your timeseries data ? thanks

Comment: That is correct, you have to feed/stream data into your own system and do the analysis there. The is how we do it on our side

Comment: I asked the question to their community and apparently Kapacitor is a data processing engine that gives the possibility to calculate custom indicators in the database. I have no idea if it is faster than doing it in a Node JS server served by a Mongodb for example - which is my plan. At least it's going to be much more easy.

Answer (score 15):

You could try [Arctic](https://github.com/manahl/arctic). Other open source column-oriented databases that you may not have considered include LucidDB and C-Store.

Comment: Thanks! Could you add a link to Arctic? The link above actually points back to this question. I'm aware of LucidDB and C-Store, but it looks like both are dead. May main question was which of the mentioned databases would actually produce the best performance.

Comment: @AndyFlury Fixed.

Comment: Interesting! Looks like this is related to this video from ManAHL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVyIxdxsyok

Comment: Yes, Arctic is AHL's tick and TimeSeries data store.  We've presented a few times on its implementation:
https://github.com/manahl/arctic/wiki Performance (from Python) is good - millions of rows/s.  Happy to answer any questions!

Answer (score 5):

(I work for Axibase)

[Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/finance/) is not open-source but it's free on single node.

Time precision is microseconds.

It supports OLCHV+VWAP aggregators in SQL and REST API with various functions for filtering by trading calendar, auction stages, indices etc.

```
SELECT datetime, symbol, close(), vwap()
  FROM atsd_trade
WHERE in_index('<index-name>')
  AND in_session(DAY, CLOSING)
  AND datetime BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-15' EXCL
GROUP BY exchange, class, symbol, PERIOD(1 DAY)
```

(I work Axibase)

Comment: Thanks Sergei, interesting product! You are the owner of Axibase right? You should always disclose this information as they are very picky about advertising products in response to questions here on stackexchange. Looks like you are using similar technologies to OpenTSDB which produces similar performance figures too (see my comment on the main question).

Comment: @AndyFlury Thanks for pointing it out. Disclosure added.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/). Free and Open Source DB, noSQL. It almost perfectly fits your case.

Comment: Thanks @AlexZeDim. Cassandra is a good NoSQL database. However it is not specifically built for time series data, so you would have to add a lot of that functionality on top yourself. As far as I know OpenTSDB can be used on top of Cassandra

Answer (score 1):

** disclosure: I work for quasardb **

Hi - you may want to run the community edition of quasardb. If your dataset if small enough (32 GB storage) - this may very well work !

https://download.quasardb.net/quasardb/nightly/server/ (get 2.1.0 that comes with native timeseries support)

It is coming with a Python/EXCEL API .. R to follow.

The community edition is 100% features complete. Just the back end storage capacity that is limited.

Cheers
Gilles